# Adding Items to List using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I brought down my classes to be as simple as possible. Below are my classes.

```cs
public class QuestionData
{
    property QuestionID int {get; set;}
    property Question String {get; set;}
    property QuestionScore int {get; set;}
    <!---Few More Properties ----!>
}
```

```cs
public class QuestionInfo
{
    property QuestionID int {get; set;}
    property Question String {get; set;}
    property QuestionFinalScore int {get; set;}
    property List<QuestionData> ListAchieved {get; set;}
}
```

Below is my Sample Data

```
Question | QuestionID | QuestionScore 
    Q1   |      1     |     10
    Q1   |      1     |     20
    Q2   |      2     |     10
    Q2   |      2     |     -5
```

After going through Group in `Linq` and with below `Query`

```cs
List<QuestionData> FinalSet = // Filled with Data Here
IEnumerable<QuestionInfo> datapoints = from f in FinalSet
    group f by new { f.QuestionID, f.Question } into fGroup
    select new QuestionInfo()
    {
        QuestionID = fGroup.Key.QuestionID
        , Question = fGroup.Key.Question,
        , QuestionFinalScore = fGroup.Sum(g => g.QuestionScore)
        //, ListAchieved = This is where IDK what to do :(
    };
```

Below is my Output

```
Question | QuestionID | QuestionScore 
    Q1   |      1     |     30
    Q2   |      2     |     5
```

Now if you see My Class `QuestionInfo`, I need to Add All `QuestionData` to my Question `ListAchieved` property so that I can show it in a list as to how the `Question` `QuestionFinalScore` ended up what it is.

Can anyone point me as to what i need to do to add all these items to my `List<QuestionData>` Property grouped by `QuestionID` and `Question`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
, ListAchieved = fGroup.ToList()
```

This puts all the items of one group into a list.

Comment: @GiladGreen If I'm not totally wrong `fGroup.ToList()` returns a `List<QuestionData>` of the QuestionDatas that achieved the QuestionFinalScore in the given group. I've double-checked my code and it works fine. But it has been a pretty long day, so it could totally be that I didn't understand correctly what the `ListAchived` should consist of.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. I thought `FinalSet` was of type of `QuestionInfo`. Your solution with the simple `.ToList()` is what needed